# Limited linux-user for Nginx configs

Tags: nginx, limited-user

I want to give access for support team to add/modify Nginx-configs and apply changes in our web-server (Oracle Linux 6 64bit).
There are not problems to give restricted file-access to nginx conf directory **only**.
But how to give permissions to reload/restart nginx proccess **only**?

Can somebody give me advice how to setup restricted access for support-team to manage nginx configs and apply changes (without permissions to browse files in other folders and without permissions to manage other processes)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo` for this, as documented here: https://gist.github.com/sheharyarn/f3d98e8cc859f092532b